# How correlation helps in compression

Tags: encoding, compression, image, correlation

Hy,
I would like to know how correlation between pixels in image helps in compression?
Also, why I would like to reduce correlation between pixels to get better compression (I found that information in one literature, but I don't understand it)?
My last question is: If correlation is R=0.9, how this information can help in compressing?

Thanks.

Comment: The "correlation helps compression" is not linked to images alone: if you can correlate one part of your data to another one, and expressing that correlation takes less place than the two individual parts, then you have compression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll make an example. Let's say that every pixel is very much correlated with the pixel above it. Instead of compressing the pixel values directly we now compress `bottomPixel - topPixel` (**the delta of the two**).

**This delta will be very small** because of the correlation. I can now use a **variable-length encoding** like arithmetic or huffman to assign less bits to small deltas and more bits to high deltas. I'll save bits that way because **small deltas occur a lot more often**.

This example generalizes to lots of cases and models (audio being one of them).