# Decorrelation in image compression

Tags: image-compression

I have learned in many articles that decorrelating the components of an image (e.g. the color transform) can improves the coding efficiency. But none explains why. And, is there a way to prove the efficiency?

Answer (score 1):

An image can be compressed if, and only if, its pixels are correlated. Any image compression method results in decorrelating the pixels. As a result, any transformation that decorrelates values can be the basis for an image compression method.

Adapted from: Data Compression: The Complete Reference. 2nd Edition - David Salomon

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14285881/how-correlation-helps-in-compression)

Answer (score 0):

first you should know how DCT and DFT and these trnasforms work.
whenver you want to encode without loss(ignoring quantization error)
you need to make the probability function uniform then the entropy will get maximize and you need less bit to encode that

e.g: in JPEG:

1.it will take the DCT and derive the frequncy content of the N*N matrix (signal)

2.by the fact that most images dont have high frequencies it will then multiply the less frequencies with higher coefficients(companding it)

3.then it will encode it to less bits

to know exactly how it works you need to read Information Theory of shanon
also this github repo helps :
https://github.com/getsanjeev/compression-DCT